# Is there a way to downgrade any Wordpress plugin after upgrade?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to downgrade any Wordpress plugin after upgrade? My client upgraded all plugins and now up-gradation of some plugin creating problem.

Comment: What plugin and what problem?

Comment: I don't know about specific plugin. client has upgraded all the plugins.

Comment: @MrXexxed - main problem is disturbed navigation http://tinyurl.com/2wzwj5e

Comment: You should try and figure out which plugin is causing you trouble. Start disabling them one by one and see which one is misbehaving.

Comment: @Ignacio- hmm i'm going to check

Comment: hmm, seems that the plugin was keeping HTML in order in some way. So, you could look for plugins that where modifying the HTML output in your templates and install the previous version.
Also, once you get this sorted, look around for alternatives to prevent clients from updating, it'll save you many headaches ;)

Comment: Use permissions to stop clients from doing admin tasks

Comment: @adam - How to stop? pls tell me more

Comment: Set your client users to editors - that way they can edit all the posts but can't do things like installing plugins, changing themes etc. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES but it's not a one-click process like upgrading was.  You need to delete the folder of the specific plugin from the wp-content/plugins directory and then upload the older version.  You should be able to find a copy of each version on the various plugin websites.

Comment: Of course, if a plugin upgraded its database structure, downgrading will be harder.

Answer (score 1):

No way other than to delete/remove them and re-install the required versions.

Answer (score -1):

No. And neither you can downgrade the WP itself. That's why they always warn us to backup our data :S

PS_ you could download an earlier version, but I guess that's not what you're asking.